# Pandas merge 2 columns from dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I've got two dictionaries:

```
game_data = {
    'game_id': range(1, 6),                
    'title': ('LOL', 'WH40K',
              'WOW', 'POE',
              'KEK'),                      
    'author_id': (1, 1, 2, 3, 5),           
    'genre_id': (1, 2, 4, 4, 1),           
    'price': (0, 0, 14, 19, 100)           
}

author_data = {
    'author_id': (1, 2, 3, 4),     
    'author_name': ('Graham McNeill',
                    'Christie Golden',
                    'Nick Jones',
                    'Slaik')       
}
```

The task is to create the dataframe using dictionaries above in this way:
new dataframe should contain only two columns: **title & author_name**:

```
   title      author_name
0    LOL   Graham McNeill
1  WH40K   Graham McNeill
2    WOW  Christie Golden
3    POE       Nick Jones
```

I've tried

```
print(pd.merge(
    df1, df2,
    left_on='title',
    right_on='author_name',
    how='inner'
))
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution (you should replace `left_on='title', right_on='author_name'` by `on='title'`):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(game_data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(author_data)

df1.merge(df2, on='author_id', how='inner')[['title', 'author_name']]
```

Output:

```
   title      author_name
0    LOL   Graham McNeill
1  WH40K   Graham McNeill
2    WOW  Christie Golden
3    POE       Nick Jones
```

Comment: Thank you! it helped me. I haven't even thought about this part: ['title', 'author_name']